# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.JPA.Dao.User_Repository' available

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

When running my SpringBoot application, I am getting this error:

@SpringBootApplication
public class BootJpAexampleApplication {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext context=SpringApplication.run(BootJpAexampleApplication.class, args);

    User_Repository userRepository = context.getBean(User_Repository.class);
    User userEntity = new User();
    
    userEntity.setNameString("Kumar ");
    userEntity.setCity("RSA");
    userEntity.setStatus("I m java developer..");
    
    User save= userRepository.save(userEntity);

    System.out.println(save);

}
}
```

I'm quite stuck on the JPA Datasource definition, because I get the following error.
This is error

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.JPA.Dao.User_Repository' available
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:341)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:332)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1150)
at com.JPA.springboot.BootJpAexampleApplication.main(BootJpAexampleApplication.java:20)

Comment: the error just tells that there is no bean of type User_Repository - check if you have such a bean

Answer (score 0):

i think is is because `User_repository` is not annotated with `@Repository` or not being scanned by Spring

please check if user_repository interface is annotated with `@Repository` and its located in package which is being scanned by Spring

Use `@ComponentScan` to mention the package name in which repository class exists!

Comment: I was used @Repository annotation but still getting error

Comment: My Interface class

Comment: @Repository
public interface User_Repository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer>
{

}

Comment: If i use Annotation of @EnableJpaRepositories("com.JPA.Dao") getting error of org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'user_Repository' defined in com.JPA.Dao.User_Repository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on BootJpAexampleApplication: Not a managed type: class com.JPA.Enity.User